# Show that for a square matrix $A$ the equality $\det(A^*) = \overline{\det(A)}$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

My idea is to start with the definition of the adjoint: 
$$\det(A^*) = \det(\overline{A^T}) = \overline{\det(A^T)} = \overline{\det(A)}.
$$
However, I do not have a proper reasoning for this step:
$\det(\overline{A^T}) = \overline{\det(A^T)}$, so I doubt if I am on the right track. Can anyone provide a way to prove this?

Comment: Either use an explicit formula for the determinant in  terms of the entries or use the fact that determinant is the product of the eigen values and eigen values of $A^{*}$ are complex conjugates of the eigen values of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. About the step you are asking for, by the [properties of complex conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Properties): $\overline{a+b}=\overline{a}+\overline{b}$ and $\overline{ab}=\overline{a}\overline{b}$. Therefore, recalling the [definition of determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_%C3%97_n_matrices) of a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, we have that
$$\overline{\det(A)}
=\overline{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k,\sigma(k)}}=
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n \overline{a_{k,\sigma(k)}}=\det(\overline{A}).$$
Notice that $\overline{\text{sgn}(\sigma)}=\text{sgn}(\sigma)$ because $\text{sgn}(\sigma)$ is $\pm 1$ (a real number).

Comment: Simpler: The determinant is a polynomial in the entries, so applying $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b}$ and $\overline{ab} = \overline{a} \overline{b}$, we get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to think about this. The determinant of a ring $R$ is the unique map $\det\colon M_n(R)\to R$ which is multilinear alternating when viewed as a function of the column vectors $\mathbf v_1,\dots,\mathbf v_n$, and such that $D(I_n)=1$. (See Lang's *Algebra* XIII.4)

Given this characterization, it is enough to show that the map $A\mapsto \overline{\det(\overline A)}$ also satisfies the necessary properties. This shows, by uniqueness, that $\overline{\det(\overline A)}=\det(A)$, or $\det(\overline A)=\overline{\det(A)}$.

An advantage of this viewpoint is that one doesn't explicitly have to work with long formulas, and can instead just check that all the simple properties hold.

**P.S.:** This is a much more general phenomenon, that for any ring homomorphism $\sigma\colon R\to R'$ and any matrix $A\in M_n(R)$, we have $\sigma(\det A)=\det(\sigma(A))$.